# Concern on Websphere Portal application file remove

Tags: websphere, portal, websphere-7, websphere-6.1, websphere-portal

i've got one issue with Websphere Portal application. The situation is when we removed one uploaded image file of Portal application from WAS intsalledApps folder path directly, that file would be regenerated by itself after we restart Websphere Portal application server. It seems that image file has been sync from somewhere else. But that websphere portal has been deployed within websphere standalone server, no dmgr node but just one application server profile. So i don't understand why that file would come out again? where is it from?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check the `installableApps` directories. But I recommend using the administration tools for this task.

Answer (score 0):

there should be a couple of directory where installation keeps their file

D:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\config\cells\nodename\applications

and the second one

D:\IBM\WebSphere\wp_profile\installedApps

check both of them, if you confirm that there is no deployment manager in this configuration.